# using nhibernate, how would i construct a query that wants the most recent 50 rows

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have a table called orders and i have a column called Last Update (and an order object with a LastUpdate property).  I want to construct a query using nhibernate to get the last 50 rows so i don't go to the database and get everything and then have to filter results in my application.

is this possible in nhibernate.  I am trying to use the LINQ api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the LINQ version of this query.

```
var orders = session.Query<Order>()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdate)
    .Take(50);
```

Here's the screen shot of the code sample...

[image: Code example]

Here's the screen shot from NHibernate Profiler...

[image: NHibernate profiler example]

Comment: tried that and it doesn't seem to do the filter at the database level.  when i run nhibernate profiler i see it returning all of the records.

Comment: I think you wanted session.Linq<Order>()

Comment: NHibernate 3.0.0.4000, this adds a TOP(50) to SQL server. And the Linq<T>() syntax has been replaced by Query<T>(). Photo of profiler coming soon.

Comment: . tested again and now seems to worked. .  something may have been cached . .

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a Criteria then use SetMaxResults(50) and do a descending sort on the date time.

Comment: do you know if its possible through the LINQ api??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SetMaxResults(50)`, although depending on which 50 rows you want (latest? first? last?) you'll probably also need to do a SortBy expression as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var orders = session.Query<Linq>()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdate)
    .Take(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general case suggesing `LastUdate` can be nullable using Linq2SQL you may write extension method to your IQueriable:

```
public static partial class FooTable
{
    public static IQueryable<FooTable> LastUpdated(this IQueryable<FooTable> queryable, int count)
    {
        return queryable.Where(x => (x.LastUdate != null))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUdate)
            .Take(count);
    }
}
```